# Fluent configuration for 0..1 relationship produces foreign keys on both sides

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using Entity Framework 5 code first... I have an app entity:

```
public class App
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Field> Fields { get; set; }

    public Field TitleField { get; set; }
}
```

And a related field entity:

```
public class Field
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] LastUpdate { get; set; }

    public App App { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Identifier { get; set; }

    public FieldType Type { get; set; }

    public string Label { get; set; }

    public int? Length { get; set; }

    public bool Required { get; set; }
}
```

I have added TitleField to App and want to configure a 0..1 relationship.
I have tried various combinations of HasOptional\WithOptional\Dependant\Principal in fluent configuration, but when I scaffold the migration I always get:

```
public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.Apps", "TitleField_Id", c => c.Long());
        AddColumn("dbo.Fields", "App_Id1", c => c.Long());
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Apps", "TitleField_Id", "dbo.Fields", "Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Fields", "App_Id1", "dbo.Apps", "Id");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Apps", "TitleField_Id");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Fields", "App_Id1");
    }
```

Why does it think I need a foreign key on both sides of the relationship when the foreign key on App is more than enough to make this work? It's possible that the 1..Many app to fields relationship is confusing things which is why I tried to be explicit using the fluent configuration.

As mentioned previously this makes no difference and I have tried all the sensible combinations that I can think of (and even some that aren't) and every time I get the same migration.

Any help would be much appreciated, let me know if you need more info.

Pete

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: No sadly not. In the end I ended up adding a new boolean property IsTitleField to the field entity instead of modelling this as a relationship.

Comment: ouch... seems like it would be a common use case, that's frustrating.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

A 1:1 relationship (one FK reference always has to be optional as one record must exist first to be referenced by the other) requires a foreign key reference on each record... Otherwise, it would be a 1:N relationship.

To suit your purpose, leave the App.TitleField reference as N:1 and add a unique constraint to the corresponding FK field (e.g. App.TitleFieldId) in the Apps table to enforce a 1:1 relationship

Answer (score 0):

Both of your Classes are referencing each other. EF Code First will interpret this as a 1 to 1 relationship. If you want you `App` class to have a `Field`, you should only set the `Field` property at the `App` class and not one referencing one another.

Try this using this convention at you `App.cs`:

```
public int FieldId { get; set; }  --> Code First recognizes the "Id" suffix by default.
public Field Field { get; set; }
```

In your DAL/Context file:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.Entity<*YOURDBSET*>().HasRequired(t => t.App).WithOptional(t => t.Field);
    }
```

Both codes will probably ensure your relationship.
In case you're still lost check this link [EF - Relationships and Navigation Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564)